# Validate if radio buttons are checked in a page on submit: AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. I have poulated the dom with some questions using factory. I have to validate if the radio button are checked. Please  give suggesstions to improve this code

**Index.html**

```
<body ng-app="quiz">
    <div id="container" ng-controller="QuizController"> 
        <button ng-click="submitfun()">submit</button>
    </div>  
</body>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('quiz', ['quiz.service','quiz.directive']);

var QuizController = function($scope, questionFactory) {
    $scope.questions_and_answers = questionFactory;
    $scope.checkList=[];    
    $scope.submitfun= function(message){
        alert('hi');         
    }   
};
```

**factory.js**

```
angular.module('quiz.service', [])
    .factory('questionFactory', function() {
        return [
            { question: "Which of these is England's official slogan for the World Cup?", answerChoices: [ "Impossible is not an English word", "One nation, one team, one dream!", "Real men wear red and white","The dream of one team, the heartbeat of millions!!" ] },
            { question:"Who was Roy Keane talking this week about when he said: \"Not everybody wants to wander around the pitch waving and crying?\" ", answerChoices:["David Moyes","John Terry","Luis Suárez","Rio Ferdinand"]}
        ];
});
```

Comment: where are your radio buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the combination of ng-disabled and ng-show directives for validation and displaying error message.

See this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/hxfQVKkGJWLVjeKsGyZA?p=preview)